# Custom functions in class c++

Tags: c++, file, class, object, fwrite

I am coding in c++ for the Nintendo DS. I am brainstorming ways to allow the game I'm helping code be modable (Meaning other people can compile mods into a separate file and they could be loaded into the game). I am using fread and fwrite for file interactions.

So I thought of something like this (I know this will not work):

```
#include "World.h"
//Where the class "World" is defined

class WorldGenerator
{
public:
    void generateWorld(World*);
};

void WorldGenerator::generateWorld(World* worldToGenerate)
{
    //Put all the trees and land in "worldToGenerate" in the normal way
}

void functionThatGetsCalled()
{
    FILE* genFile;
    //Initialize genFile

    World mainWorld;
    WorldGenerator gen;
    fread(&gen, sizeof(gen), genFile);
    //Loads in new generator which might have an alternate generator

    gen.generateWorld(mainWorld);
    //Generates world using whatever generator was in genFile
}
```

And then the WorldGenerator class function generateWorld would be changed and tan abject would be written to the file using fwrite. Now I am almost positive this would not work.

**So, is there a name for something in c++ that would essentially allow custom functions in a class, like described?**

If not, how else can functions be compiled into separate modules? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you are looking for object (de)serialization to be able to reconstruct the WorldGenerator object from a file.

Comment: @Yuan Which function?

Comment: virtual function, interface and plugin are keywords you should look for. what you want is a plugin system but implementing this depends on the operating system and the compiler you are using. i dont know if it is even possible to have sharedobjects/dlls on the nintendo ds

Comment: Try [dlopen](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html).

Comment: @Pradhan Let me look into dlopen. This sounds like what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you want to modularize your application with plugins, so dlopen is your path. If you want to load an instantiated object from file, deserialization would be it.